# Running a parameter query in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, parameterized

I am trying to run the following query in a VBA function. I keep getting "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

```
strSQL = "Parameters [Report Date] DateTime;" & vbCrLf & _
                    "SELECT SCF.code AS [Stock Code], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "SCF.desc AS [Description], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "SCF.grp AS [Product Group]," & vbCrLf & _
                    "SCF.qCurr AS [Closing Stock], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "SCF.abp AS [Avg Price], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "Sum(([Closing Stock]*[Avg Price])) AS [STOCK VALUE], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "MaxDate.tDate AS [Last Transaction Date], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "Sum(IIf(([Last Transaction Date]>[Report Date]),([Closing Stock]*[Avg Price]),0)) AS [After Report Date], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "DateDiff(""d"",[Last Transaction Date],[Report Date]) AS [Days since Last Transaction], " & vbCrLf & _
                    "[Report Date]" & vbCrLf & _
            "INTO [FinReport] " & vbCrLf & _
            "FROM SCF RIGHT JOIN MaxDate ON MaxDate.parent = SCF.this "
strSQL = strSQL & _
            "WHERE (SCF.qCurr <> 0) " & vbCrLf & _
            "GROUP BY SCF.code, " & vbCrLf & _
                        "SCF.desc, " & vbCrLf & _
                        "SCF.grp, " & vbCrLf & _
                        "SCF.qCurr, " & vbCrLf & _
                        "SCF.abp, " & vbCrLf & _
                        "MaxDate.tDate" & vbCrLf & _
            "ORDER BY MaxDate.tDate;"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
qdf.Parameters("[Report Date]").Value = Form_IO_Form.ReportDate_TB.Value
qdf.Execute
```

I have verified that all fields (other than [Report Date] of course) exist ***and the query runs by itself as an access query*** (pop up asks for [Report Date]).

Help!

Edit 1:
As requested here is the DB file as a ZIP. It is an Access 2007 .accdb file
   [DB File](http://www.mediafire.com/?b5pkih22zio2y4q)

Comment: I'll note, that you shouldn't really require the `& vbCrLf ` in each line. The compiler doesn't care about new lines. Unless of course, you really need to print out the query for viewing. In any case, vbNewLine would be the preferred anyway.

Comment: @codeslave: the vbcrlf is to make the query string more readable and understandable for me and any future programmer. I'll amend my code and use vbnewline ...

Comment: @CodeSlave Why do you prefer `vbNewLine` instead of `vbCrLf`?

Comment: vbCrLf is a hard coded carriage return and line feed [Chr(13) + Chr(10)]; vbNewLine is a platform-specific new line character, either [Chr(13) + Chr(10)] or [Chr(13)]. http://codespecs.blogspot.ca/2011/12/what-is-difference-between-vbcrlf-vs.html It's kind of like \n in C. Conceivably, MS could release a version of MS Access for a non-Windows OS. In which case the first would break, and but the second should work without modification. vbNewLine is more descriptive of what it actually is doing.

Comment: Access' db engine accepts `Chr(13)`, `Chr(10)`, or `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` as line breaks in SQL statements.  So regarding line breaks in queries, `vbNewLine` offers no advantage unless/until MS releases a version of MS Access for a non-Windows OS **and** changes the behavior of the db engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement will trigger error #3122 from the db engine:

`You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'DateDiff("d",[Last Transaction Date],[Report Date])' as part of an aggregate function.`

That error will cause the statement to fail before the db engine even considers any parameters.

When you build a SQL statement with VBA, it's better to start with one the db engine will accept.  Then you should also follow the sound advice from @mwolfe02 to `Debug.Print strSQL` ... to give yourself an opportunity to examine the completed statement you're asking the db engine to execute.

**Edit**: Having examined the ACCDB file you uploaded, I still don't understand why your query doesn't trigger error #3122.  However the query does work as a saved query and can work when you execute it from VBA code.  The reason you got the complaint about "too few parameters" is that you weren't actually executing the temporary QueryDef you created.  Instead you were attempting to execute the SQL text like this:

```
' Execute created Query '
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

If you change to this approach (as you indicated in your question), it works without error:

```
qdf.Execute
```

Comment: the vbcrlf is there for just that reason - I use it to make the query string mire readable for debugging. Please note that,ad I have highlighted, the query runs just fine when run as a normal access query

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I don't know why error 3122 doesn't trigger on that either, but the previous DBA had written the query so and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have a typo in one of your field names.  The easiest way to find it is to throw a `Debug.Print strSQL` line immediately before your `Set qdf...` line.

Then create a new query in the Access UI, switch to SQL view, paste in the SQL text from the immediate window, and execute the query.  Access will prompt you for the `Report Date` (which you are expecting) and the mistyped name of one of your fields.

Comment: If you hard-code a date (eg, `#5/28/2012#`) in place of your reference to the form textbox (ie, `Form_IO_Form.ReportDate_TB.Value`) do you still get the error message?

Comment: Yes. Tried that - same error. Even when I use 
    `Form_IO_From.ReportDate_TB.value = Date` 
to get the current system date.